# Total is missing while create calculated measure using parallelperiod

Tags: sql, null, mdx

Below is my query.

```
    WITH  
       MEMBER [Measures].[Quantity - Prior Year] As  
         ( 
           PARALLELPERIOD(
             [Date].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year]
           , 2
           , [Date].[Fiscal Year].CurrentMember
           )
         ,[Measures].[Order Quantity]
         )  
     SELECT 
       {
        [Measures].[Order Quantity], 
        [Measures].[Quantity - Prior Year]
       } ON AXIS(0)
     , {DrilldownLevel([Date].[Fiscal])} ON AXIS(1)
     FROM [Adventure Works]  
       CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FORMATTED_VALUE
```

[image]

but the grand totals for calculated measure is always NULL?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking why "Quantity - Prior Year" is NULL for "All Periods", "FY 2002", or "FY 2003"?

Comment: @jhenninger24 no, I think he is asking why is the single cell for "Quantity - Prior Year" and "All Periods" NULL? rather than the sum [null + null + 24096 + 82181] ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "All Periods" is the system-generated `All` member for the `[Date].[Fiscal Year]` hierarchy.

From this [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/database-dimensions-configure-the-all-level-for-attribute-hierarchies), it is the member with pre-aggregated measure values for all members in the `[Date].[Fiscal Year]` hierarchy. When this member is passed to the `ParallelPeriod()` function, it doesn't make sense to lag the aggregated value back 2 fiscal years, so it returns null.